# How can you make the one-line version of Perl grep into an alias?

Tags: bash, perl, macintosh, macos

I found that we can use

```
perl -wnle "/RE/ and print"
```

such as

```
perl -wnle "/^.{0,80}$/ and print"
```

or

```
grep -ri someText * | perl -wnle "/^.{0,80}$/ and print"
```

to exclude lines longer than 80 characters.

But how do you make it into an alias in Bash?

I tried:

```
alias pgrep='perl -wnle "/$1/ and print"'
```

and then

```
grep -ri someText * | pgrep "^.{0,80}$"
```

but it'd say

```
Can't open ^.{0,80}$: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 5):

`alias` in `bash` are *not* designed to take arguments and won't know to what to do with it if provided with one. They should generally be avoided and should only be used for really simple command name alternatives.

Recommend using a function instead. Note that `pgrep` is a valid Linux binary which shouldn't be used, recommend using a non ambiguous name instead.

```
perlgrep() {
    perl -wnle "/$1/ and print"
}
```

and now call it as

```
perlgrep '^.{0,80}$'
```

The reason for your error though is, since `alias` couldn't have handed the argument itself, when the expansion happened, the command became like this

```
grep -ri someText * | perl -wnle "/$1/ and print" '^.{0,80}$'
```

which is incorrect, because `perl` thinks `'^.{0,80}$` as a filename that it needs to open and run the regex on.

Comment: that's because `alias echo2='echo $1'` worked... but many people have advised against using alias... I guess when arguments are used?  just that `echo2` worked can Perl grep be made working if using an alias?

Comment: @nopole: I'm not sure of a case how that `echo2` alias could have worked. Only way I can think of is, in that case `$1` would have already been set in the function/script you are invoking this alias on but `echo2 foobar` could never work

Comment: @nopole Try `set -- foo` and then run your alias.

Comment: @Inian actually `echo2` works on a Mac

Comment: @muru thanks... somehow on my Mac `alias pg='perl -wnle "/$1/ and print"' ; set -- foo ; grep -ri someText * | pg "^.{0,80}$"` doesn't work... what is `set -- foo` btw... why `foo`?

Comment: @nopole I meant `alias echo2='echo $1'` then `set -- foo` and `echo2 bar` to see how your `echo2` alias really worked.

Comment: @muru then it would print out `foo bar`... I wonder how that happened?

Comment: @nopole: Are you still not accepting the fact, that aliases don't take arguments? See [BashFAQ/080 - How can I make an alias that takes an argument?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/080)

Comment: @Inian aliases can take arguments. I have this in my `~/.bashrc`: `alias c='_c=$(fc -nl -0); bc -l <<<${_c#*c} #'`. This allows me to type commands like `c 7 * 8` => `56` without bothering that `*` will be expanded (In fact, I use something else than `bc` that can handle units and parse 8R2 as 8.2 Ohm, but let's keep it simple ;-)).

Comment: @iruvar: Yes it did look odd. Changed it now

Answer (score 1):

Note that `pcregrep` (from [the PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/)) and GNU `grep -P` (when built with PCRE support) can take perl-like regular expressions and `grep -P` will work OK on UTF-8 data when in UTF-8 locales.

If you wanted to use `perl` instead, you could define a script or function to do so. Aliases won't do as aliases are just aliases, just meant to replace one string with another.

You could do:

```
perlgrep() (
  export RE="${1?}"; shift
  exec perl -Mopen=locale -Twnle '
    BEGIN {$ret = 1; $several_files = @ARGV > 1}
    if (/$ENV{RE}/) {
      $ret = 0;
      print $several_files ? "$ARGV: $_" : $_
    }
    END {exit $ret}' -- "$@"
)
```

But beware of [the implications of running `perl -n` on arbitrary file names](/q/170013) which are only partly mitigated by the `-T` option above.

Also, with `-Mopen=locale`, we're decoding the input and encoding the output as per the locale's charset, but file names themselves will be *encoded* but not *decoded*, which means that if filenames have byte values above 127, that won't work properly unless the locale's charset is iso8859-1.

In the end, you just need to *decode* the lines of input for matching only. You don't need to reencode it, not to decode/encode the file names.

So, instead, with recent versions of `perl`, you could do:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl --
use warnings;
use strict;
use Encode::Locale;
use Encode;

my $re = shift @ARGV;
my $several_files = @ARGV > 1;
my $ret = 1;

while (<<>>) {
  if (decode(locale => $_) =~ $re) {
    $ret = 0;
    print $several_files ? "$ARGV: $_" : $_
  }
}
exit $ret;
```

To prevent arbitrary code injection from the arguments, regexp operators like `(?{code})`, `(??{code})` are disabled. If you want them back, you can add a `use re 'eval';` towards the top of that script.

Comment: is it available on the Mac? my grep on Mac doesn't have a `-P` option... and I checked egrep and fgrep and they don't have it either

Comment: @nopole, on macOS, I believe there are a number of opensource package managers (homebrew, fink...) that you can use to install opensource utilities like GNU grep. macOS tools are based on FreeBSD, and FreeBSD grep is still based on GNU grep (albeit a very old version, and one without -P support), but IIRC macOS eventually replaced it with their own possibly so they don't have to distribute its source code. `pcregrep` itself comes with the pcre (perl-compatible regular expression) library.